# What programming language was Windows Vista programmed in?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, operating-system

Which programming language(s) were used to code Windows Vista?

Comment: Mostly LOLCODE and INTERCAL, I think.

Comment: Come on Robert, Vista is not _that_ slow... (*just kidding*)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From working with the Windows CE operating system I'd say its a mix of C for the old school code and interfaces, and a lot of C++ behind the scenes for drivers and other code. It (WinCE) uses C++ in the drivers behind a C interface to the rest of the system.

Now I'm going to guesstimate and say there are many bits of C# and other code in it now as well.

Comment: WinCE is a different beast to NT.

Comment: Yes, but it's still an educated guess based on similarities between the WinCE and Win32 API's and the time frame in which both were developed.
If one really wants to know then someone should track down the Windows NT/2000 code that was leaked a few years back.

Comment: I take it from the down mods that people don't like posting educated guesses as answers even though they contain the same languages as the other upmodded answers.

Answer (score 20):

Well, the Windows kernel is still almost entirely C. However, there are different aspects that use C++, say some parts of the shell and so forth. The core is C. Other languages, perhaps even .NET might be used in some corners for certain applications but C is the OS language of choice in Windows.

Comment: There's a research project by Microsoft called Singularity, a 99% managed code (C#) Operating System. 

<a href="http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/groups/os/Singularity/">Link</a>

Comment: Singularity uses some assembly and C to boot up, I assume the runtime/JIT is also written in C and the rest is all C#. Its quite interesting as it statically verifies the managed code before execution, compiles it to native code on the fly and then executes it. I must reread their SIGOPS papers.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I know about Singularity. But that's a research project. :)

Answer (score 3):

Multiple languages would have been used to create Vista.

For the low level parts, C and assembly language.

The majority would have been in C / C++.

Some of the higher level applications may have been written in managed code.

Answer (score 2):

I would imagine a combination of C/C++ and Assembly (for device interaction).

Comment: ugh. C/C++ means absolutely nothing.

Comment: It's some combination of Objective/C/++/#/++0x/.  You know, those languages with that letter in it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, the [Windows Research Kernel](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/sharedsource/windowsacademic/researchkernelkit.mspx) (which is, afaik, based on XP) is written in C. I assume the rest is too. However, just because the kernel is written in C, doesn't mean the entire operating system is. There are also libraries, tools and applications without which Windows would be pretty useless. Of these, I *assume* that most are written in C, C++ or C#, though thats just an assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Garry is always right, seriously if Microsoft deny C is getting replaced they should really check with him before they go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Windows vista was programmed in multiple language for different things. The entire kernel was written in C, while others parts used C++, possibly .NET as well.

Answer (score -1):

Vista operating system arrived in numerous variants for use in places like England and Kandohar as stated in the rules for the use of Vista and its definition. Some were coded in something like RCODE for home computing and others may have been coded in COMAL, VBAS or ICODE for computers based on a Commodore (CBM) 63 used in some computer base units. What the higher level languages compiled into is confidential and is the preserve of the authoring person in England, the team supporting versions created for other countries by Microsoft, with variations for install on computers for use in the workplace having a different policy inside regarding protection of business data for compliance with privacy rules.

Answer (score -1):

well having gone through most of the comments, there are quite a good guys out here who do it with only C, yes most of the kernels in the world are written using C the powerful programming language C and as pinch of salt the assembly of course for the disk and video interfaces and for some memory (DMA).