# Windows: What programming language?

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What programming language was Windows Vista programmed in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380988/what-programming-language-was-windows-vista-programmed-in)

What is the primary programming language in which Windows was written? I'm pretty sure the kernel of all versions of Windows was/is written in C. Is this correct? Now, what about items such as the command line tools such as ipconfig, ping, cmd, net, etc? Are these tools written in C or C++? What about services such as the print spooler, terminal services, IIS, etc? Are these written in C or C++? Lastly, are there any components that are written in Assembly language? Thanks for your answers.

Comment: http://www.google.se/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=What+language+is+Windows+written+in%3F

Answer (score 0):

Most of those components and applications would be C++.

I doubt there are entire components in assembly - maybe pieces of some components.

And yes, most of the kernel is in C.

I believe the inside windows or the windows internals books would be good places to start if you want to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

[Windows NT System Overview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/cc767881.aspx) says,

> Most of the source code for Windows NT
>   is written in C or C++. These
>   high-level languages make it
>   relatively easy to port Windows NT to
>   different types of workstations. The
>   same source code can be recompiled to
>   build versions of Windows NT that are
>   specific to each processor's
>   instruction set.
>
> A small amount of the code in Windows
>   NT is written in assembly language.
>   Typically, this is code that either
>   interacts directly with a computer's
>   hardware, or needs to run extremely
>   fast.